# Not able to open any files after updating the Android Studio from 4.0.1 to 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

After opening an existing project in the updated Android Studio, I tried opening the files. But after double clicking on the file name nothing happening in the Android Studio. No files are opening.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Be sure that Android Studio checks only for stable versions: You can check that in your editor: Appearance and behavior --> System Settings --> Updates: Stable Channel

Comment: Settings options is also not opening in this studio.

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved as I down versioned to 4.1.1. Looks like 4.1.2 is not the stable version. Please use 4.1.1 instead.